# Why my Django application could not connect to postgres inside docker

Tags: django, postgresql, docker, docker-compose

I'm trying to launch my django app inside docker container

**docker-compose.yml**

```
version: '3.8'

services:
  api:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: ./Dockerfile-local
    ports:
      - "8000:8000"
    entrypoint: ./entrypoint-local.sh
    env_file:
      - .env-local
    links:
      - postgresql
  postgresql:
    image: postgres:12.4
    restart: always
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_USER=postgres
      - POSTGRES_DB=frov_db
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=postgres
      - POSTGRES_HOST=postgresql
      - POSTGRES_PORT=5432
      - PGDATA=/var/lib/postgresql/data/pgdata
      - C_FORCE_ROOT=true
    ports:
      - '5433:5432'
```

**Dockerfile-local**

```
FROM python:3.8-slim

ENV PYTHONDONTWRITEBYTECODE 1

WORKDIR /usr/src/app

COPY Pipfile.lock Pipfile ./
RUN pip install -U setuptools pip pipenv && pipenv install --system --deploy --ignore-pipfile --dev

COPY . .

RUN touch /var/log/filebeat.log && chmod 664 /var/log/filebeat.log \
&& chmod +x ./entrypoint-local.sh
```

**entrypoint-local.sh**

```
#!/bin/bash

python manage.py collectstatic --no-input --settings frov.settings.default

python manage.py migrate --settings frov.settings.default
python manage.py seed

gunicorn -b 0.0.0.0:8000 --workers=1 --env DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=frov.settings.default frov.wsgi:application
```

**.env-local**

```
DEBUG=True
DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=frov.settings.default
DB_NAME=frov_db
DB_USER=postgres
DB_PASS=postgres
DB_HOST=postgresql
DB_PORT=5433
```

And now I have now idea, why do I get such error

```
api_1         | psycopg2.OperationalError: could not connect to server: Connection refused
api_1         |     Is the server running on host "postgresql" (172.21.0.2) and accepting
api_1         |     TCP/IP connections on port 5433?
```

Can anyone hepls me? I just can't figure out where the mistake can take place

Comment: `5433` is the port exposed to the host. Inside docker network the postgres is still accessible by `postgresql:5432`, so try to switch the port in the env to `5432`

Comment: @awesoon - oh, yes, you are right. If you want, you can post an answer and I will accept it

Comment: @Stefano `5432` is a container port exposed as `5433` host port. However, even [docs](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#ports) refer to `5433` port as `the publicly exposed port`. So I apologize for confusion, but I don't think I'm wrong here.

Comment: you're right. I apologize.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This [`ports` config section](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#ports):

```
ports:
  - '5433:5432'
```

Exposes `5432` container port to `5433` host port. However within the docker network the db is still accessible on the `5432` port, so you need to change your `.env` file to use `5432` port.

If you don't need other apps to access db from the host you may omit this `ports` section at all (you'll still be able to connect to it using e.g. `docker-compose exec`)